# Does the Lie bracket relation $[\Gamma(D), \Gamma(E)] \subseteq \Gamma(E)$ imply the flow relation $d\theta_t(E) \subseteq E$?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and let $D, E \subseteq TM$ be two distributions on $M$ such that
$$[\Gamma(D), \Gamma(E)] \subseteq \Gamma(E),$$
where $\Gamma(\cdot)$ is the space of smooth sections and $[\cdot, \cdot]$ is the Lie bracket of vector fields. Let $X \in \Gamma(D)$ and let $\theta_t$ be the flow of $X$. Is it true that
$$d\theta_t(E_p) \subseteq E_{\theta_t(p)}\tag{1}$$
for all $p \in M$? (In which case, it is actually an equality.)

Some special cases are easy to check. For example, if $D = E$, then $E$ is involutive, so the flow lines of $X$ are contained in the leafs of $E$, and (1) follows. I'm not sure about the general case.

Comment: Isn't $d\theta_t(Y_p)=[X,Y]_{\theta_t(p)}$ (perhaps up to sign), so the answer is automatically "yes"?

Comment: @IvoTerek Doesn't your formula imply that $d\theta_t = 0$ by the following argument? Take any $v \in T_pM$ and let $Y$ be a vector field supported in a small neighbourhood of $p$ with $Y_p = v$. Then $d\theta_t(v) = [X, Y]_{\theta_t(p)} = 0$ if $\theta_t(p)$ is outside the support of $Y$.

Comment: Hmm. Yes, I don't see any flaw in your argument.

Comment: @IvoTerek That equality is not true. Lie brackets only correspond to *infinitesimal* flows, so your expression should have some kind of derivative w.r.t. $t$ on the left side.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, the condition condition $[\Gamma(D),\Gamma(E)]\subseteq\Gamma(E)$ implies that $D\subseteq E$.

Comment: @Kajelad How about $D = TM$ and $E = 0$?

Comment: @SimonParker Right; I should have added the requirements that $D,E$ are of rank $\ge 1$. In that case, you can assume $D\nsubseteq E$ and $[\Gamma(D),\Gamma(E)]\subseteq\Gamma(E)$ and derive a contradiction.